# .netcore 3.1 - Windows Hosting Bundle - Installs .Net Core Runtime 3.1.0 preview3 instead of 3.1.0 (final release version)

Tags: iis, hosting, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am upgrading an existing .net core 3.0 web api project to 3.1. I downloaded the Windows Hosting bundle for .Net Core 3.1 from [Microsoft's official site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

As mentioned in the website:

> The ASP.NET Core Runtime enables you to run existing web/server
>   applications. **On Windows, we recommended installing the Hosting Bundle
>   which includes the .NET Core Runtime and IIS support.**

After I installed the hosting bundle, I checked in Control Panel to verify whether it is installed properly. To my surprise I found that, the **.Net Core Runtime version is 3.1.0 preview3 is installed instead of only 3.1.0**. Is this behavior intentional? I am worried because it should not throw any errors/issues after I deployed the code. Please suggest your views.. Should I manually uninstall the preview version and install the 3.1.0 version?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't click on the wrong link or executable?  I've installed it too, and didn't get 3.1 Preview 3. What is the download's filename?

Comment: here is the file name: "dotnet-hosting-3.1.0-win.exe". Is it not the correct one?

Comment: That's a known issue, and those guys forgot to name it correctly. It is supposed to be fixed in 3.1.1 release.

Comment: @LexLi could you please provide the link where it says it's a known issue. The link will help others who are reading this post. Thanks!!

Comment: I read that from a private email, so I cannot share anything further.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: @Sascha you can uninstall it and reinstall the individual files instead of the hosting bundle (I did like this as I didn't have other options). To use the hosting bundle, we have to wait until MS fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

I want to share the link because it has bored me to finding. I seen many advertisements on internet for membering azure etc. i don't like those things!!!. Microsoft please dont make this things. if its free than share for all on all there!!

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score 4):

I can see the .net core runtime  3.1.0 preivew 3 are being installed when I am trying to install 3.1.0 hosting bundle.

[image]

However, if I install  3.1 .0 preview version seperately, `dotnet --info` will show

[image]

However, if you try to run `dotnet --info` in 3.1.0 environment, its version is

[image]

So I'm sure 3.1.0 offical release has been installed on my side. I also confirm this with our engineer and it should be fixed in the future version.